# serverless (sls) deploy specific resource

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

How to deploy a specific AWS resource using [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/)?
I know it supports deploying specific lambda functions using `sls deploy -f <function>`. Wondering if there is similar option to target AWS resource?

In my use case, I have an API, ~50 Lambdas, Dynamodb, SQS, Cognito user pools etc. Each time I make a change to Cognito (or anything other than lambda code), I have to run complete `sls deploy` which takes ~10-15 minutes. Wondering if there is a way to skip complete deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to skip full deployment, as Serverless Framework uses CloudFormation under the hood and it has to update the whole stack. The only resource that you can update separately are functions, as you mentioned, but it's only intended for development and it does not recognize all properties during an update.